# Generate alter table scripts using sqitch

Tags: sqitch

Lets say I create a table in snowflake called Employee with EmployeeID and EmployeeName. I would check in the Create table script for this table to my github repo and get this deployed using sqitch. If in the next release, there is a need to add a new column to this table, can I accomplish this by just adding a new column to the existing Create table scripts. Does sqitch have the ability to compare github and my target DB to understand and generate ALTER scripts in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I did some more research and figured that Sqitch follows the imperative approach. Which means that it needs us to write the Alter statements in this case.

Comment: Would you mind sharing where you found the info? I am digging through Sqitch manual, and can't figure this out.

Comment: This Article explains the Declarative VS the Imperative approach (that sqitch follows) :
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowflake-CI-CD-using-Flyway-and-Azure-DevOps-Pipeline-Part-2

Comment: Thank you. I also found this q&a which confirms that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086596/altering-table-with-sqitch-rework-command?rq=1